# gssapi-with-mic authentication from Windows to CentOS 7.9

Tags: ssh, sshd, authentication, kerberos

We are a Windows shop with some CentOS servers, which we recently joined to our domain using `realmd`.
I can successfully log into each CentOS using my domain username and password. Now, I'm trying to set up passwordless authentication using the GSSAPI mechanism (sorry if this is not the correct naming, I just learned about this).
I setup my `.ssh\config` file on my Windows laptop like this:

```
Host *
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
```

Now, without editing any configuration on my server, I can successfully login in Server A without inserting my password, but not in the others Server B-F. I checked the `sshd_config` files on each server, and they are all the same.

Using `ssh -vvv` on both Server A and another where the login fails, the only difference I see is

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a gssapi-with-mic packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51   <---- on Server A is debug3: receive packet: type 61
```

Where can I look to understand why?

PS: I am not a domain admin and have no power over the AD configuration, but I'm pretty sure that nothing has been configured differently for Server A.

EDIT: This is the SSH log (same log in `/var/log/secure` and `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service`) for Server A where I can successfully log in using `gssapi-with-mic`.

```
Apr  4 09:53:14 serverA sshd[24003]: Authorized to domain\\myuser, krb5 principal myuser@DOMAIN.LOCAL (ssh_gssapi_krb5_cmdok)
Apr  4 09:53:14 serverA sshd[24003]: Accepted gssapi-with-mic for domain\\myuser from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 52070 ssh2
Apr  4 09:53:14 serverA sshd[24003]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user domain\myuser by (uid=0)
```

On other servers, I can't find no indication of login attempts using `gssapi-with-mic`.

Comment: What do you see in the sshd service's logs?

Comment: @user1686 edited the question to add logs

Comment: Does the broken server report _anything at all_ about the connection? Can you raise the broken server's log level (e.g. `LogLevel DEBUG1`) and check again?